# $X^p - t$ irreducible in $K[X]$ with $K:=\text{Quot}(\mathbb{F}_p[t])$

Tags: ring-theory, field-theory, finite-fields

I've heard a teacher say that this also follows by the Eisenstein criterion by checking with $t$. But then $t$ would have to be prime in order for Eisenstein to have any validity, but $t$ is arbitrary. So Eisenstein can't be used here, right?

Comment: $t$ is not arbitrary! It's a formal element, just as $X$ is an element of $K[X]$. Since $t\mid f(t)g(t)\implies t\mid f(t)$ or $t\mid g(t)$, $t$ is prime.

Comment: Your first sentence makes no sense to me. If $t$ was replaced by $1$ it'd stop being irreducible while the assertion still holds.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up, Mathmo123. @quid, yeah, you're right. That didn't make any sense ;-)

Comment: Do you still need an answer? I can give one, but I won't if you know everything you need already.